# Create Passwordless SSH login without exectuting SSH-KEYGEN on Client?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, openssh, key-authentication

The normal installation/configuration of SSH on a client requires the use of ssh-keygen to create a local private/public key pair in the .ssh folder of the user's profile.

To configure the normal, secure login process, the client user's public key must be 'copied' to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file to in the server user's home folder.

These operations must be performed while the server's sshd configuration is set to allow `PasswordAuthentication` (yes) and to have the `AuthorizedKeysFile` value set to the current location of the user's `authorized_keys` file.

That location may not be in the user's actual `/home` folder if the server is running Centos 7, which encrypts the user folders, preventing access during ssh login. The `AuthorizedKeysFile` value would likely be `/etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys` in that case.

However, to create a login for the server root account on a client, especially from... say a Mac, creating a `root` user presents problems.

Therefore, how does one create a user on a client linux/bsd system who will be recognized by ssh on the server, be mapped to the correct alternate (%u) folder for verifying the login's public key when the sshd is properly configured to prevent `PasswordAuthentication`, `AllowRootLogin, and` require `PublicKeyAuthentication`?

Mostly, how do I create a public key for the `root` user on the client that can be `ssh-copy-id` or cat-copied to the necessary hacked-in location on the server's `/etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys` folder?

Thanks...

Comment: "These operations must be performed while the server's sshd configuration is set to allow PasswordAuthentication (yes) ... " Noooope. That's what you have administrators and key management systems for. The public key is, well, not private, so it can be sent out-of-band to an admin who can then add it to the relevant authorized_keys file; or you have an automated tool which takes form input from somewhere and adds the keys.

Comment: Ok, I'm willing to be corrected. But I was unable to perform the ssh-copy-id with PasswordAuthentication set to NO under any circumstance for any user over the 8 or 9 days I have been trying to find a solution to getting a normal and a root user setup for 'passwordless login'. But an explanation of the principles is not sufficient to provide me with a working solution. Again, are you speaking from a Centos 7 with encrypted user folders persepective? Thanks

Comment: The point is that you don't use `ssh-copy-id`: that's the wrong tool here. You send the key to an admin who will (or use an automated setup which will) copy the public key to the appropriate location. CentOS 7 or encrypted user or whatever makes no difference.

Comment: For example, OpenSSH can get keys from a command instead of from a file. One way to use this would be to run a Gitlab server which is itself protected by password + 2FA; this command can use the Gitlab API to get the public key for the relevant user.